# How can I calculate the distance between two cameras (opencv-python)?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm using Python. I have two cameras (left and right) and I'm calibrating them using opencv and its function "calibrateCamera", so I got intrinsics and extrinsics parameters of both cameras and photos.

I also have photos taken at the same time with both cameras, so now I have to calculate the distance between them...

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use euclidean distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance specifically the three dimensions

Comment: I thought about it too (using numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)), but, how can I get those points (a and b)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082938/how-do-i-get-coordinates-of-image-shown-in-opencv