# Searching for images on screen is taking too long

Tags: python, performance

I am new to python and I have found a project that interests me. It is a simple script that presses the keyboard keys when a button prompt is displayed on the screen. I took photos of the possible button prompts and I am scanning for them. the program works very well but is too slow.

For example let's say there is 12 button prompts, my program can only enter 10 before time runs out. I believe this is because of the 9 things it is scanning for. Is there any other way to accomplish what I am doing but faster, or is there another library I could try?

```
#method that actually looks for photos on screen
def look(self):
    self.z = imagesearch("press_z2.jpg")
    self.c = imagesearch("press_c2.jpg")
    self.s = imagesearch("press_s2.jpg")
    self.x = imagesearch("press_x2.jpg")
    self.w = imagesearch("press_w2.jpg")
    self.q = imagesearch("press_q2.jpg")
    self.e = imagesearch("press_e2.jpg")
    self.d = imagesearch("press_d2.jpg")
    self.a = imagesearch("press_a2.jpg")

def run(self):
    while True:
        self.look()
```

My code was posting weird so here is a link to the full thing:
https://pastebin.com/5pWDfwXy

Comment: Your `run()` method contains an infinite loop — so you need to modify it so there's some way for the `while` loop to end and so the function can return. Maybe you don't need the loop at all — just remove the `while True:` and fix the indentation accordingly. Note I haven't looked a your full code, please post all question-related code here.

Comment: but I want the program to infinitely look for these photos until closed, I believe what is missing from the full code is that this is being run in a threading.Thread class

Comment: It would help if you showed what the image looks like and a couple of the buttons.

Comment: Threads don't actually run concurrently in Python because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) and instead take turns running — so it's more like a cooperative-multitasking system. If one of the threads doesn't periodically do something that releases the GIL, then the other threads will hardly get a chance to run at all.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I don't think seeing the photos is relevant at all.

Comment: @martineau I was thinking that the buttons may be similar to each other and OP could maybe initially locate potential candidates coarsely and then focus in on candidates to differentiate. Or the buttons might all be located in one area of image so OP wouldn't need to search entire image. Or maybe their colours make them easy to locate. Have a look at this question and you'll see what I am getting at... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133112/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It's not a speed-of-processing problem, it's the OP's naive attempt to use multi-threading — which is why I said the images themselves are irrelevant. That's not to say there aren't other problems, too, just an attempt to focus on the primary issue at this point.

Comment: @martineau Oh, I interpreted it as a speed problem because the title says it *"takes too long"* and, inside the question, OP says *"time runs out"*. I may be wrong though, I have been wrong many times before

Comment: The button detection is working. Just slow, from what I understand from all this is python does not support actual multithreading and I should try this in a different language?

Comment: The problem is speed. I am however searching for a letter in the same position on the screen everytime.  Maybe I can search the one position instead of the entire screen?

Comment: Python _does_ do real multi-processing, although it involves a fair amount of overhead — but it might be a workable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is not actual threading in python, use multiprocessing instead